# Continuity of the spectral radius

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, perturbation-theory

Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a nonnegative irreducible matrix with strictly positive entries on its main diagonal. Then $M$ is primitive and by the Perron-Frobenius Theorem we know that the maximal eigenvalue of $M$ is its spectral radius $\rho(M)$. Moreover, there exists a strictly positive (component wise) $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$Mx = \rho(M) x.$$

Now, for every $t > 0$, consider the perturbed matrix $M(t) := M+tD$ where $D\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a diagonal matrix with strictly positive entries on its diagonal. Then $M(t)$ is also a primitive matrix and by the same theorem we know the existence of $x(t)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ strictly positive such that $$M(t)x(t) = \rho(M(t))x(t).$$
Then we have 
$$\lim_{t \downarrow 0} \rho(M(t)) = \rho(M).$$

My questions:

- How to prove that? (references are also enough and welcome :))
- Is it possible to get sufficient/necessary conditions on $C$ so that if I replace $D$ by $C$ then the result still holds?

A bit of context:

- This argument (or a very similar version of it) is used in Corollary 5.2 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.1626v3.pdf).
- A similar argument is also discussed in the introduction of [this paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022247X07006592/1-s2.0-S0022247X07006592-main.pdf?_tid=12c076d0-29e0-11e4-b04d-00000aacb35f&acdnat=1408700489_000ed4d8e3da7f14b8e2ffe5b9eceda6) however they assume it be know and don't provide references to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C$ be a nonnegative matrix and $M(t)=M+tC$ (a primitive matrix). Then $\rho(M(T))$ is the maximal eigenvalue of $M(t)$. Let $spectrum(M(t))=(\lambda_i(t))$ with $\lambda_1(t)>|\lambda_2(t)|\geq |\lambda_3(t)|\geq\cdots$. Since $\lim_{t↓0}M(t)=M(0)$, $\lim_{t↓0}\rho(M(t))=\rho(M)$. Moreover , when $t$ decreases, $\rho(M(t))$ decreases too.

EDIT:(with  correction). When, for every $t$, the eigenvalues of $M(t)$ are real, we can write $\lambda_1(t)\geq \cdots\geq \lambda_n(t)$. Then the functions $\lambda_i(t)$ are continuous. That is no more the case when the eigenvalues are complex ; for instance there may be a continuous arc that connects $\lambda_2(1)$ and $\lambda_n(0)$. Yet $\lambda_1(t)=\rho(M(t))$ is continuous ; indeed there are continuous functions $x_j(t),j\leq n$ s.t. for every $t$, $x_j(t)$ is an eigenvalue of $M(t)$. Then $\sup_j |x_j(t)|=\lambda_1(t)=\rho(M(t))$ is continuous. Moreover $\rho(M(t))$ is a real analytic function ; the reason is because $\lambda_1(t)$ is a REAL and SIMPLE eigenvalue of $M(t)$. For a proof, cf.

http://www.math.upenn.edu/~kazdan/509S07/eigenv5b.pdf

Comment: Thanks! Could you provide a reference for "this general result valid for any sequence of matrices" please?

Comment: Somehow this is exactly the result I am looking for...

Comment: @ Moaleroa:                                               Ref 1: http://books.google.ca/books?id=7u1V_abVrkIC&lpg=PA32&pg=PA26#v=snippet&q=polynomial%20roots&f=false  p.26.      Ref 2: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1965-016-01/S0002-9939-1965-0171902-8/S0002-9939-1965-0171902-8.pdf

Comment: Ok I understand that the roots $\lambda_1(t),\ldots,\lambda_n(t)$ of $\det(M(t))$ are continuous however I don't understand how you can guarantee that $\lambda_1(t_0) >|\lambda_i(t_0)|$ implies $\lambda_1(t) >|\lambda_i(t)|$ for every $0<t<t_0$.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the kind of answer I was expecting: good explanation + good reference :)